# "Token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression" when using UIKitForMac

Tags: xcode11, ios13, uikitformac

So I'm trying to compile my iOS project for the mac, and when I try to use

`#if !targetEnvironment(UIKitForMac)`

I'm getting the error from the title.

I tried setting the build target to iOS 13, but didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using objective-c and not swift you should use:

```
#if !TARGET_OS_UIKITFORMAC
#endif
```

Comment: That was it! Is this documented anywhere? Even when selecting Objective-C in the official docs don't show this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/creating_a_mac_version_of_your_ipad_app?language=objc

Comment: It think this is a documentation bug because it shows the same code regardless the selected language. It was shown in the WWDC talk, and code completion helps as well. :-)

Comment: Code completion is not doing anything for me :( Might be because my computer is super slow with Xcode 11. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Objective-C**

```
#if !TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST
// Code to exclude from Mac.
#endif
```

**Swift**

```
#if !targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
// Code to exclude from Mac.
#endif
```

Sources:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/creating_a_mac_version_of_your_ipad_app?language=objc
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating_a_mac_version_of_your_ipad_app